# Can I still claim a free copy of Minecraft Windows 10 Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just got Windows 10 and I was looking forward for the Windows 10 Edition of Minecraft. Can I still get it with my Mojang account? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: That is a better title, and the tags are nice too. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get Minecraft Java for free if you have purchased Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389361/can-you-get-minecraft-java-for-free-if-you-have-purchased-minecraft-bedrock) (which has an answer that covers both ways, and the answer to this question is outdated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can still obtain your Minecraft Windows 10 Edition Copy.

[image: http://prntscr.com/95vg1u]

Go to [account.mojang.com/me](http://account.mojang.com/me) then click the Claim your free copy button. After that, login to your Microsoft account. Then... you are going to have your gift code right there!

[image: http://prntscr.com/95vgmm]

Comment: Thanks for your edit @angussidney ! By the way, how do I put pictures? I tried to but it didn't work..

Comment: Click on the little button that looks like an image in the toolbar of the editor. Then drag-and-drop the image to have it uploaded to the pro SE Imgur account which means your images will be kept forever. I think the button is the sixth one on the left.