# Can you get Minecraft Java for free if you have purchased Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently downloaded Minecraft from the Microsoft Store and have been playing for a month or two. I decided to try out a few mods and that led me to realise that I had Minecraft Bedrock not Java, and after reading a few articles I believe it is not possible to downloads mods on Minecraft Bedrock. Is there any way for me to 'switch' to Java or get a discount or refunded on Minecraft to get Minecraft Bedrock?

Or if you can download mods on Bedrock, could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes** (and vice-versa), as of June 7, 2022. Note that this does not apply to Android, iOS, PlayStation, Switch, or any other platform besides PC, Mac, or Linux.

> Starting June 7, all players that have either Java Edition or Bedrock Edition **will receive the edition they do not currently own for free**, right in the Minecraft Launcher. So if you own Java, you’ll get Bedrock – and vice versa.

<sup>Source: [*JAVA & BEDROCK EDITION FOR PC IS OUT ON JUNE 7*, 2022-06-04 Mojang Studios blog post](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/java---bedrock-edition-pc-out-june-7)</sup>

> We’ve been working on some big changes, and we’re excited to announce
> that Minecraft: Java Edition and Minecraft for Windows (aka “Bedrock
> Edition”) are now being sold as a single product! What does this mean
> for you? Well, if you’ve never bought Minecraft before, you can now
> get both Java and Bedrock for one low price, also called Minecraft:
> Java & Bedrock Edition for PC.
>
> If you *have* bought Minecraft before, you’re now getting the other
> edition for free. Woot! Follow these steps to redeem it:
>
> 1. [Click here](https://aka.ms/JavaBedrockEdition) to go to the Microsoft Store listing for Minecraft: Java & Bedrock for PC.
> 2. Sign-in to the Microsoft Store with your Microsoft account. Please note: If you still only have a Mojang account and have not yet
>    migrated to a Microsoft account, you will have to migrate to a
>    Microsoft account before you can redeem your new game. Don’t fret,
>    migrating your account is easy and free! ([Click
>    here](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360050865492-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Account-Migration-FAQ)
>    to learn more about account migration or [migrate your
>    account](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/mojang-account-move) now to
>    take advantage of this offer.)
> 3. Once you’re signed in, instead of a “Buy” button you should see a button that says “Get.” Click this button – and now you own both
>    editions!
>
> #### How do I run or play either version of Minecraft?
>
> Once you’ve completed the steps above, including logging into the
> Microsoft Store, you can now download the Minecraft Launcher.
>
> - To play Minecraft: Java Edition, [**download and install the correct launcher**](https://aka.ms/MinecraftLauncher) for your
>   operating system. Sign into the Launcher using your Microsoft account,
>   and you will be able to run Java Edition.
> - To play Minecraft: Bedrock Edition, you will need a device running Windows 10 or 11 to [**download and install the newest version of the
>   Launcher**](https://aka.ms/MinecraftLauncher), within which you can
>   launch and play Minecraft: Bedrock Edition. Sign into the Launcher
>   using your Microsoft account, and you will be able to run Minecraft:
>   Bedrock Edition.

> ###### I have Minecraft Bedrock Edition on Switch/Mobile/PlayStation/another platform besides PC, Mac or Linux. Do I get Java Edition for free?
>
> Minecraft: Java & Bedrock Edition for PC is only for the PC, Mac, and Linux platforms at the moment. This offer does not apply to consoles or other versions of Minecraft.

<sup>Source: [**Minecraft: Java & Bedrock Edition for PC FAQ**](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/6657208607501)</sup>

Comment: @galacticininja I have a follow-up question. I bought two Minecraft Bedrock accounts on different devices but using the same Microsoft Store account. Can I get two different Java accounts (one on each device) and if so how?

Comment: @JacobBoughton It is not possible to buy Minecraft: Windows 10/11 Edition twice using the same Microsoft Account. Are you sure you bought it twice and the account was the same?

Comment: @galacticninja I am pretty sure but will check again and get back to you in a bit.

Comment: @galacticninja I have had a look at the purchase history as you said it says I only purchased one bedrock account on that account. I cannot think of any other accounts I could have used to buy Minecraft Windows. Is there any way of finding out which account I used to purchase the game on each device?

Comment: @JacobBoughton "*Is there any way of finding out which account I used to purchase the game on each device?*" Check out the solution at [I don't remember which account I purchased Minecraft Windows 10 edition on.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-dont-remember-which-account-i-purchased/22d52780-74d4-4a6c-8645-5f3ece7d4068) If you still can't find out which account, you might need to contact [Mojang Support](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/requests/new) about it.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately no. However, there are plans for this to change in the summer of 2022; see [Ray Wu's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/397205/274742) for more information.

<sub>*This answer will remain in-tact for historical reasons, but it will be updated to support the most current information as the situation changes.*</sub>

---

Technically, Minecraft is sold as a separate product on each platform you can play it on, even though there two types remaining:

- [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)
- [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)

For example, even though I own [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) for [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10), [xbox-one](/questions/tagged/xbox-one), and [ios](/questions/tagged/ios), I had to purchase each product separately:

- Minecraft
- Minecraft for Windows 10
- Minecraft: Pocket Edition

The same was true for [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition). I had to purchase it as a separate product, even though I owned three other versions at the time of purchase. Subsequently, this will also hold true for every other platform that [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) is available on.

---

<sub>***Note**: See the [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) tag for a complete list of supported platforms.*</sub>

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**
[All previous owners of Minecraft: Windows 10/11 Edition now have access to Java Edition in the Minecraft Launcher.](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/6657208607501)

---

Yes, all owners of Minecraft: Windows 10/11 Edition (the one on the Microsoft Store as specified in the question) will be able to install Minecraft: Java Edition sometime in Summer 2022. This answer will be updated when more details are released.

Note: This offer does not extend to any non-desktop versions of Minecraft

Source: https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4607523809933-Buy-Minecraft-PC-Bundle-Get-Both-Games-

Comment: Please provide official sources to your answer.

Comment: @Tacoタコス added it

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer to reflect this information and pointed future readers to your answer.